What's the difference between ''disconcert'' ''unnerve'' and ''unsettle''?
The rapid spread of the virus disconcerted/unnerved/unsettled the entire world.
She was disconcerted/unnerved/unsettled by the fact that she had to give a speech in front of 500 people.
When you are writing an exam and you start seeing others hand in their exams as the time is running out, you are going to be disconcerted/unnerved/unsettled by the fact that you haven't finished yet.

Please do and post some research or we have to.

They're all much of a muchness. Offhand I can't even think of a context where only 1 or 2 of the 3 are likely to be used. And I certainly cant think of any contexts where the choice of term would significantly affect the meaning of the containing utterance.

You should know by now that we expect you to say what you have already found out about the words in question. Personally, I would say that one is disconcerted by something unexpected (you open the door thinking you know who it is, and it's someone completely different) and unsettled by an ongoing difficult situation.

..and unnerved by an event that shakes your confidence.

I’m voting to close this question because there is no consensus on the relative grading of adjectives like this

My understanding of the connotation of these synonyms is a slight difference in degree or strength.

"Unsettled," would be the mildest, i.e., just some qualms. "When the Fasten Seatbelt sign flashed, I was somewhat unsettled... as was my stomach"

"Disconcerted," would be a bit stronger, i.e., taken aback. "However, when the flight attendants jumped to their seats, I was a bit disconcerted."

"Unnerved," would be stronger yet, i.e., one has lost their nerve, and terror is imminent. "Seeing flames pour from an engine, I admit to being unnerved."



Thank you. So they mean basically the same but the worried state someone is in always varies in terms of strength?

As in "unhappy" vs. "miserable"
